# TeamCity - MSBuild runner exits with not zero code

Tags: .net, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I've had TeamCity running for a long time, with no problems.

I then upgraded to TeamCity 8, and now all my .Net projects fail when launching the Test build step.

The only error message I see is this: `MSBuild runner exits with not zero code`

The test part of my log, looks like this:

```
[10:39:08][Step 1/2] Process exited with code 0
[10:39:08]Step 2/2: Test (MSTest) (20s)
[10:39:08][Step 2/2] Starting: F:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe #TeamCityImplicit
[10:39:08][Step 2/2] in directory: F:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\382c54c35fd97a3e
[10:39:13][Step 2/2] JetBrains dotCover Console Runner v2.2.515.44. Copyright (c) 2009-2013 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.
[10:39:13][Step 2/2] 
[10:39:28][Step 2/2] [JetBrains dotCover] Coverage session started [6/29/2013 10:39:28 AM]
[10:39:28][Step 2/2] [JetBrains dotCover] Coverage session finished with errors: Can't initialize profiler.
[10:39:28][Step 2/2] 
[10:39:28][Step 2/2] Product installation directory has no read access rights for WinRT applications.. 
[10:39:28][Step 2/2] ##teamcity[importData type='dotNetCoverage' tool='dotcover' file='F:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\coverage_dotcover79745141367270310401.data']
[10:39:29][Step 2/2] Importing data from 'F:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\coverage_dotcover79745141367270310401.data' (not existing file) with 'dotNetCoverage' processor
[10:39:29][Step 2/2] Rejected coverage report file: F:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\coverage_dotcover79745141367270310401.data size: 0. File is empty or does not exist
[10:39:29][Step 2/2] Process exited with code -2
[10:39:29][Step 2/2] Step Test (MSTest) failed
[10:39:29]Waiting for 1 service processes to complete
[10:39:29]Publishing internal artifacts
[10:39:29][Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
[10:39:29]Build finished
```

If I look at the `teamcity-build.log` file, I can see it says err on the line where the `NUitLauncher` is executed:

```
[2013-06-29 10:39:08,134] out - 
[2013-06-29 10:39:08,134] out -     14 Warning(s)
[2013-06-29 10:39:08,134] out -     0 Error(s)
[2013-06-29 10:39:08,134] out - 
[2013-06-29 10:39:08,134] out - Time Elapsed 00:00:19.87
[2013-06-29 10:39:08,485] out - Process exited with code 0
[2013-06-29 10:39:08,736] out - ----------------------------------------- [ Backstage::Build and Test #62 (buildId = 874) ] -----------------------------------------
[2013-06-29 10:39:08,739] out - Starting: F:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe #TeamCityImplicit
[2013-06-29 10:39:08,739] out - in directory: F:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\382c54c35fd97a3e
[2013-06-29 10:39:08,746] err - F:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe #TeamCityImplicit
[2013-06-29 10:39:13,336] out - JetBrains dotCover Console Runner v2.2.515.44. Copyright (c) 2009-2013 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.
[2013-06-29 10:39:13,336] out - JetBrains dotCover Console Runner v2.2.515.44. Copyright (c) 2009-2013 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.
[2013-06-29 10:39:13,336] out - 
[2013-06-29 10:39:13,337] out - 
[2013-06-29 10:39:28,002] out - [JetBrains dotCover] Coverage session started [6/29/2013 10:39:28 AM]
[2013-06-29 10:39:28,002] out - [JetBrains dotCover] Coverage session started [6/29/2013 10:39:28 AM]
[2013-06-29 10:39:28,752] out - [JetBrains dotCover] Coverage session finished with errors: Can't initialize profiler.
[2013-06-29 10:39:28,753] out - [JetBrains dotCover] Coverage session finished with errors: Can't initialize profiler.
[2013-06-29 10:39:28,753] out - 
[2013-06-29 10:39:28,753] out - 
[2013-06-29 10:39:28,753] out - Product installation directory has no read access rights for WinRT applications.. 
[2013-06-29 10:39:28,753] out - Product installation directory has no read access rights for WinRT applications.. 
[2013-06-29 10:39:29,170] out - Process exited with code -2
```

Anyone else seen this? Is there a place to find more extensive log information?

Comment: I had a very similar issue, and following the instructions here fixed it: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=49448495

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a dotCover related issue.

I fixed it by installing the latest version of dotCover from here: http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/

Then, in each build configuration that defines the MSTest build step and uses dotCover, you need to override the dotCover home directory with the one where you just installed dotCover.

Comment: I followed the steps described here: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/440995 to update the dotCover.zip that TC uses, so the "you need to override the dotCover home directory with the one where you just installed dotCover" will not be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue and I fixed it by following [this](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=49448495) article. However, I assigned the permission to the TeamCity installation folder (`C:\TeamCity` in my case) instead of the `Program Files (x86)` folder. Seems that dotCover bundled with TeamCity is installed there instead of the program files folder.

Comment: Same here, yet for the installation folder of the build agent (in my case C:\BuildAgent)